# Does OneLogin support client_credentials?

Tags: oauth, client, token, credentials, onelogin

Having trouble finding the information in OneLogin regarding `client_credentials`.

I'm just looking to setup the flow for an API that we have.
A client app will request a token using `client_id`, `client_secret`, then use that token to access our API.  Was hoping that OneLogin was a token provider, and could even assist in some way.

I've gotten as far as setting up a developer account, then creating an API, but I have been unable to obtain an access token from the API - and even if I did it seems to be a token I would use to access the other features in the OneLogin API.

Can anyone tell me if what I'm trying t achieve is possible with OneLogin?
Machine to Machine, or client to API communication.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you go through this https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting this up with OpenID connect:

https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/password-grant

This will generate a token (and refresh token) that can be validated against OL.